# Trying to join parent / primary table to child / foreign table in sequelize

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get all my articles data from articles table but also user data from users table i've made. I using sequelize to build database to MySQL database and also as a ORM, here's the snippet code

**USER TABLE**

```
    const User = sequelize.define('users', ({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  nama: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,  
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  }
}))
```

**ARTICLES CODE**

```
    const Articles = sequelize.define('articles', ({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  gambar: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  userId: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
  }
}))
```

**the relation**

```
    User.hasMany(Articles, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
})
Articles.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId'
})
```

**the ORM i've try**

```
Articles.findAll({
    include: [User]
  })
```

it is always return that users table is not associated to artiles

Answer (score 0):

You have to use as key word during creating relation ship.

```
Articles.belongsTo(User, {
 as: 'user',
 foreignKey: 'userId'
})
```

and then update form

```
Articles.findAll({include: [{
 model: model.User,
 as: 'user'
}]})
```